# Evaluating $ \lim_{n \to \infty} {\sqrt[n]{\frac{(2n - 1)!}{n!}}} $

Tags: limits, factorial

I have such limit to solve:
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} {\sqrt[n]{\frac{(2n - 1)!}{n!}}}
$$
I understand that with the n-root I should go to $e^{\ln n}$, but the real problem cause factorials. What can I do with them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is that
$(n!)^{1/n} \approx \dfrac{n}{e}
$
and
$n^{1/n}\to 1$

So

$\begin{array}\\
\left(\dfrac{(2n - 1)!}{n!}\right)^{1/n}
&=\dfrac{(2n - 1)!^{1/n}}{n!^{1/n}}\\
&=\dfrac{(2n)!^{1/n}}{(2n)^{1/n}n!^{1/n}}\\
&\approx\dfrac{((2n)!^{1/(2n)})^2}{(2n)^{1/n}n!^{1/n}}\\
&\approx\dfrac{(2n/e)^2}{n/e}\\
&\approx \dfrac{4n}{e}\\
&\to \infty\\
\end{array}
$

Answer (score 4):

$$\sqrt[n]{\frac{(2n-1)!}{n!}}=\sqrt[n]{\prod_{k=1}^{n-1} (n+k)}\ge
\sqrt[n]{\prod_{k=1}^{n-1} n}= \sqrt[n]{n^{n-1}}=n(\sqrt[n]{n})^{-1}\to+\infty$$
because $\sqrt[n]{n}\to 1$

Comment: This shows the problem is easier than Stirling's approximation, and easier than $(n!)^{1/n} \approx \dfrac{n}{e}$.

Comment: @Bongo: Very nice derivation. (+1)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Use *[Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation)*

\begin{align*}
n!\sim\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n
\end{align*}

Comment: Can it be done without it? Because I'm not sure if I'm allowed to do ane approximations

Answer (score 1):

Consider the more general problem of
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} {\sqrt[n]{\frac{(an +b)!}{n!}}}$$ Let
$$A_n={\sqrt[n]{\frac{(an +b)!}{n!}}}\implies \log(A_n)=\frac 1n \left(\log[(an+b)!]-\log(n!]\right)$$ Using twice Stirling approximation and continuing with Taylor series for large $n$, then
$$ \log(A_n)=a\log(a)+(a-1)\log \left(\frac{n}{e}\right)+\frac{\left(b+\frac{1}{2}\right) \log (a)+b \log (n)}{n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$ Notice that $b$ does not play any role in the limit.

Now, consider the three cases : $0<a<1$, $a=1$ and $a>1$